# C++ to compare vectors, faster way

Tags: c++, performance, vector, compare

if there a faster way to find a specific vector from list of vectors? I do vector comparison and that takes for ever to do and i have millions of records.

I'm using openmp

this is what i have so far

```
#pragma omp parallel for
                            for(int i=0;i<crossed.size();i++){
                                    #pragma omp flush (exit)
                                    if(!exit && (crossed[i]== vectors)){

                                            loop = i;
                                            found = true;
                                            exit = true;
                                            #pragma omp flush (exit)
                                    }
                            }

                            if(found == false){
                                    crossed.push_back(vectors);
                                    cross.push_back(0);
                            }
                            else{
                                    cross[loop] = cross[loop]+1;
                            }
```

Comment: What problem are you solving? Maybe there is a data structure or algorithm which is better suited than a vector of vectors. Maybe you can sort your data and then binary search?

Comment: If you must compare multiple vectors like this you might consider storing hash information for each vector and comparing the hashes.  You would still need to compare two vectors with equal hashes, but you can immediately cull out hashes which are different - which would gain you a lot of speed.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out whether a graph isomorphic or not. In order to do that i have to multiply each point in the vector by alpha then check whether i can find repeated once. Then i count them and compare with other graphs to find non isomorphic graphs. if you guys understand the math then it would great helpful to figure out faster algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you are willing to change your data structures a bit.

One easy way to speed up your comparisons is to use a checksum. I mean, literally check the sum. As you build the vectors, keep a running total of the sum of each one (as long as you are consistent with your data types, overflow doesn't matter). Then, instead of comparing the entire vectors, only compare the sums - then  you only have compare the vectors if the sums match up.

To go even further, you can sort your vectors by checksum...This might only be worthwhile if you have a lot of vectors, since it reduces your checksum search from n to log(n)

Comment: +1 / a hash would be better than a sum though.  And, there's no need to "sort the vectors by checksum" - just sort the single checksum/vector-id index.

Comment: a standard hash would have to be recalculated every time an element was added to the vector...with millions of elements, I think you'd lose a lot of time.

Comment: a vector hash that XORs all element hashes *with* the sum is a reasonable approach for that scenario... the hash aspect differentiates cases where sum is weak e.g. {10, -10} vs {0, 0}, {1, 9} vs {10}, while the sum helps with e.g. {3, 3, 3} vs {3}.  Trickier having O(1) cpu & mem way to generate a value sensitive to order that copes with inserts/erases e.g. {1, 3} vs {3, 1}, or {1, 3, 5} vs {5, 1, 3} - maybe also XOR in hashes of the differences between adjacent elements (e.g. for above cases {2} vs {-2}, {2, 2} vs {-4, 2}) - prone to cancellation though :-(.